# Yii2 prepend the language to the URL using UrlManager::createUrl()

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to prepend the language e.g `en` or `bg` like `www.domain.com/language/` with the `createUrl()` method of the `UrlManager` class.

What I am trying just for the test is:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\components;

class UrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($params)
    {
        $url = parent::createUrl($params);

        return "/en{$url}";
    }
}
```

And I have the class added in my `urlManager`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'frontend\components\UrlManager',
    ...
],
```

From this I expected `www.domain.com/en` but the language is missing. Maybe I misunderstood the `createUrl` method. What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are prepending the `/en` to the URL that is returned from the `parent::createUrl()`. it will show you like `/enhttp://example.com/controller/action`, what you want is to append right after the domain name and then append the rest of the URL, so you need to `explode()` the `URL` and insert your desired chunk `en` inside the desired position and you can do that by using `array_splice()`.

Just for the correction, you can use the following

```
<?php

namespace frontend\components;


class UrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($params)
    {
        $url = parent::createUrl($params);
        $chunks=explode('/', $url);

        array_splice($chunks,3,0,"en");
        return implode('/',$chunks);
    }
}
```

Now when you will call the

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/controller/action']);
```

it will generate

```
http://example.com/en/controller/action
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to include language into your URL rules:

```
'rules' => [
    '<lang:(en|bg)>' => 'site/homepage',
    '<lang:(en|bg)>/about' => 'site/about',
    // ...
],
```

And inject language as param in `createUrl()` if it is not explicitly provided:

```
class UrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager {

    public function createUrl($params) {
        if (empty($params['lang'])) {
            $params['lang'] = 'en';
        }

        return parent::createUrl($params);
    }
}
```

Now you can create URL as usual, and provide language only when you want to change default language:

```
Url::to(['site/about']);                  // /en/about
Url::to(['site/about', 'lang' => 'en']);  // /en/about
Url::to(['site/about', 'lang' => 'bg']);  // /bg/about
```

And you can get current language by:

```
Yii::$app->request->get('lang', 'en');
```